# How do I activate a single row from a list?

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity Investment Lists displaying that contains Five rows from the Database, the status is Initially set to Pending. What I want to do is add an Activate function button(React) to each results rows such that when activate button is clicked on a row it will get the Investment ID and perform the Activation Function and change the status to "Active" . I'm sending to a POST request but I have issue getting the row ID. What could I be doing wrong ?

This is the **Investment entity**

```
public class Investment 

   {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    //@Column(nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.bethsaida.org.models.Customer.class, 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id") 
    private Customer customer ;
     
   @Column(name = "AccountNumber", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int accountNumber;
    private String category;
    private BigDecimal principal;
    //private BigDecimal netInvestmentAmount;
    private BigDecimal currentInterest;
    private BigDecimal maturityInterest;
    private String tenure;
    private String marketer;
    private String investmentPackage;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate startDate;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate maturityDate;
    
    private int rate;
```

This is the **Service class** where the Activate logic is implemented

```
public void activateInvestment(Investment investment, Long id)
      {
        if(!(investment.getRate() <= 0)) 
        investment.setStatus(InvestmentStatus.Active);
        else {
            System.out.println("Investment Rate Can't be Null");
        }
      }
```

This is the **Controller** class

```
 @PostMapping(value="/activateInvestment/{id}")
    public void activateInvestment(@RequestBody Investment investment, @PathVariable Long id)  
    {
        investmentService.activateInvestment(investment, id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your @PathVariable Long id doesn't do anything, why is that included in the request when it doesn't do anything?

It is generally recommended that you to use a DTO-object that you map to your entity-object. I'm unsure, but I don't think there is an automatic persistance for your Investment-object when you receive it in a request. That means that you can't just change a value of the object and hope that it will be changed in the database.

Please take a look at the following.

https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
public void activateInvestment(InvestmentDTO investmentDto, Long id)  {

    if(!(investmentDto.getRate() <= 0))  {
        Investment investment = getInvestmentFromId(id);
        investment.setStatus(InvestmentStatus.Active);
        investment.setRate(investmentDto.getRate());
        investmentRepository.save(investment); //If not in a transaction
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Investment Rate Can't be Null");
    }

}

private Investment getInvestmentFromId(Long id) {
    return investmentRepository.getFromId(id);
}
```

And your controller class would be:

```
 @PostMapping(value="/activateInvestment/{id}")
    public void activateInvestment(@RequestBody InvestmentDTO investmentDto, @PathVariable Long id)  
    {
        investmentService.activateInvestment(investmentDto, id);
    }
```